# SQL return name of most popular / unpopular category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried for quite a while but I can't get any of the statements I try to work. Here are simplified versions of the tables and what I want to achieve:

apps table

```
app_id      app_category
--------------------------
1           2
2           4
3           2
4           1
```

categories table

```
category_id  category_name
-------------------------------
1            Arcade and Action
2            Brain and Puzzle        
3            Casual
4            Casino
```

I want my statement to return the name of the most popular category, and also another one to return the most un-popular category if possible.

For example, the most popular category is Brain and Puzzle as there are two apps with id = 2 in their category field.

I have tried quite a variety of selects and would appreciate anyone's input.
Thanks

Comment: please provide a more descriptive title.

Comment: What would you have said? I cant think of anythng else.

Comment: The concept you want to learn is about the SQL JOIN.  Find a good tutorial on JOIN and go from there.

Comment: Perhaps: return the name of the most popular category, and also another one to return the most un-popular category

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
select category_name, count(apps.app_category)
from categories
left join apps on apps.app_category = categories.category_id
group by category_name
order by count(apps.app_category)
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0b75/5

Comment: This will not show category 3 as the least popular category since it's filtered out in the join.

Answer (score 2):

Most popular category:

```
select * 
from categories 
where category_id = (select category_id from apps group by category_id order by count(*) desc limit 1)
```

Least popular category:

```
select * 
from categories 
where category_id = (select category_id from apps group by category_id order by count(*) limit 1)
```

Comment: Good point: it doesn't account for categories that aren't used at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most popular

```
select top 1 category_name, count(*)
from categories
inner apps on apps.app_category = categories.category_id
group by category_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Least popular

```
select top 1 category_name, count(*)
from categories
inner apps on apps.app_category = categories.category_id
group by category_id
order by count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.app_category) as AppCount, c.category_name
FROM apps a
INNER JOIN categories c on a.app_category = c.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id    
ORDER BY COUNT(a.app_category)
```

Something like this should give you a count of the occurrences from which you can select the most and least popular.

Answer (score 1):

```
select category_name, count(app_id) 
from apps right join categories on (app_category = category_id) 
group by category_name 
order by count(app_id) desc
```

The first result will be the most popular, the last the least popular - this will also show categories with 0 apps.

Should you only want 1 result, you could add `LIMIT 1` and change the order (`asc` for the least popular, `desc` for the most popular).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/465c81/5